# Get index (match number) of a match in a regex.matches

Tags: c#, regex, match

How can I get the index of a match iterated using for each in regex.matches??

Comment: I want the index of match or we can use to call as its match number from the matched Collections..

Answer (score 0):

Each `Match` object in the collection has an `Index` property. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try it as follows

```
 string strInput = "YourString";

 Regex regex = new Regex("Your Regex to match");
 var m = regex.Match(strInput);
 if (m.Success)
      {
          foreach (var matches in regex.Matches(strInput))
           {
              if (m.Success)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
                 }

                 m = m.NextMatch();
            }
        }
```

Comment: the match.index returns an Int which corresponds the index of match string in a given text.. I already solved this by declaring a variable and let it iterate in the loop. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The Match.Index will return the position of the Matched Item's first character on the original string.

The MatchCollection only implements the `ICollection` interface and does not implement `IList`,so i think its not possible to retrieve the index from matchcollection for an item directly.

But you could use a `Collection.CopyTo` to move that to an array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695671.aspx

Array does have an [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx) which you can use to retrieve the index back.